# Couchbase View is empty

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-view

If I try to retrieve a list of documents from a Couchbase server via a view with the Java SDK I get an empty result list:

```java
ViewResult result = dataManager.getBucket().query(ViewQuery.from("_design/dev_task", "byID"));
List<ViewRow> rows = result.allRows(); // rows is empty
```

However, in the web console the same view has a non-empty filtered result list. A retrieval by document ID, on the other hand, works flawlessly:

```java
JsonDocument taskDocument = dataManager.getBucket().get("task1", JsonDocument.class);
// taskDocument contains the document for task1
```

The query was defined as:

```java
function (doc, meta) {
  if (typeof(doc.taskID) == "number") {
    emit(doc.taskID, doc);
  }
}
```

and has the following name:

[image]

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution after reading [this blog entry](http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.de/2012/12/couchbase-101-create-views-mapreduce.html). The problem is the first parameter of the `.from` method: The `_design/dev_` prefix must be avoided. So instead of calling

```java
ViewQuery.from("_design/dev_task", "byID")
```

I have to use

```java
ViewQuery.from("task", "byID")
```

This leaves me with a non-empty array of rows!

Comment: those two lines are exactly the same

Comment: @DanLevin Thank you for this comment. I fixed the second line.

Comment: np, unfortunately i still get view not found error :(
any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm... currently, I am not actively involved in Couchbase any more. So, my knowledge is already "rusting away". Have you tried scalabilityinvolved's answer? You could also just post your own issues in a new post to get input from more experienced users.

Comment: Make sure you are querying the production view (which is the published dev view). Also, make sure when you are using the good names: the dev view usually has a dev_ prefix and the production view a design_ prefix. You can query the production view without using any prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Have you published the view? I'm going to guess that the SDK is running in production mode, so document retrieval will work as the document exists but for views it won't be looking in the development views as your screenshot above shows.

Comment: The view has not been published, yet. How can I see which mode the SDK is running in? I tried to set an enviroment variable with `System.setProperty("viewmode", "development");`. This, however, did not change anything.

Comment: Usually it defaults to production mode if I remember correctly, you can see in startup logs the SDK will log out which mode it is in.  I'd just publish the view and see if that makes it work, if it does then problem solved and if not at least we can look at something else as the problem.

Comment: The console does not mention any mode. So I just published the view and did not notice any behavioural change; `rows` remains empty. Do you have any other ideas?